# convert mysql_connect to joomla-based connect

Tags: database, post, joomla, mysql-connect

I have been struggling with this for a couple days now, but can't get it to work.
I'm currently building a website in Joomla and added a puzzle-game page into it. What I want to do is, save the time-score and create a simple top-10 score list.

I got it to work by what I think is the hard way ;) by using a `<form method="post" action="include/dbscore.php">` function. In the 'dbscore.php' file I got the following code:

```html
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","[my db username]","[my db password]");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 
mysql_select_db("[my db name]", $con);
 

$sql="INSERT INTO uhkbw_puzzel_score (fname, lname, time, date)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[time]','".date('d-M-Y')."')";
 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Your score is succesfully saved";
 
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

This does the trick and posts the data I want into the database, but I feel there must be a much simpler and safer way, since Joomla already should know the db name/passw. However the puzzel-game index.php itself is located in a separate folder inside the joomla directory and loaded through an iframe into joomla and is not a standard joomla module or component...

I already tried using the `$db = JFactory::getDBO();` methode, but I must do something wrong

Any ideas?

Comment: Joomla is a CMS, therefore you **do not** create custom PHP pages and define them in your form action. Joomla uses extensions, so if you want to create a puzzle, then create a component or module. Either one, there is lots of information on the Joomla documentation and the same goes for database queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I did implement it and it's working great. What i'm trying to say is that your answer is not very helpful... The puzzle page is just to add a little fun to the site, and since I couldn't find a nice extension for this one I got one I liked from 'Codecanyon'. No one has to 'manage the content' of this game, so why not implement it in an iframe? Or maybe you can elaborate on why i **do not** use custom php in joomla?

Comment: I could write a whole essay on why custom PHP pages should not be implemented in Joomla but as a simple answer, I will say because it defies the whole point of Joomla and may poses security issues if not done properly. Using an iframe wouldn't be my personal choice but you can do it if you wish. Instead, I would turn it into a simple module and embed the module in an article. To get a base structure for your module, you can use my [Module Generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/module-generator.html) I made a while back which will give you a blank and installable base module to start with

Comment: Thanks Lodder! I indeed didn't need an essay, just some simple explanation why, so knowing that it might cause security issues is a good reason not to do it. I will give your generator a try and see if I can implement the game into a module. I guess thats also why the JFactory::getDBO() didn't work, because it wasn't part of the CMS itself.